# Can I tell kernel to save for my application range of ports?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am developing a software in which external software can use it, this external software can use ports that I use, I want to be able to save a range of ports to be available only for my software and when the external software wan't to use it they will get an error.

Is there any system call that tells the kernel to save range of ports for my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as your application starts, you can open the ports and bind to them, no reason to reserve them anymore. *Before* your application starts, you can't use any system call.

The system administrator can, on linux, do something like

```
# echo 30000 31000 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
```

which means the kernel will ONLY use that range of ports when it assigns a port number randomly. There's a [sysctl](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-increase-outgoing-network-sockets-range.html) to go along with it as well. So you might, in theory, reserve ports 64000-65000 for your application and tell the admin of the machine your software runs on to use

```
# echo 1024 64000 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
```

somewhere early in the boot process.

However, I *strongly* recommend against that - any sysadmin with at least a little experience will tell you to get your effing software right. This kind of dependency makes administration a mess, and you totally lose if you're trying to use several different software packages needing different port ranges on one machine.

The best thing you can do is open and bind a socket for each of the ports you want to reserve before running any external program.

BTW, i had a similar problem once, on a machine that mounted NFS directories early in the boot stage, which would, from time to time, use ports 993 and 995 locally, which prevented the ssl versions of pop3d and imapd from starting up. I solved that by writing a small program that bound to those ports, starting that program even before NFS did anything, and killed it again in the boot scripts for pop3d and imapd. Maybe something like this could be a solution for you as well, if some other software uses your ports before your program starts up. But again, i'd consider this an evil hack, not something well-written software should depend on.